# bi-Hamiltonian structure of the Sine-Gordon equation

Tags: integrable-systems

It is well known that the sine-Gordon equation in laboratory (or light-cone) coordinates,
\begin{align}
\ddot\phi-\phi''=\sin\phi,\\
\dot\varphi'=\sin\varphi,
\end{align}
respectively, is an integrable system [[1]](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.30.1262). However, I have been searching in the literature for the bi-Hamiltonian structure of the sine-Gordon equation, and I've found mathematical literature that I really do not understand (I am a theoretical physicist). Just like the KdV case, which is easily to find in the literature (Lenard, 1964; Drazin & Johnson, 1983; Das, 1989, etc.) that it is a bi-Hamiltonian system,
\begin{align}
\dot u=uu'+u'''=\partial_x\frac{\delta H_0}{\delta u}=\mathcal{D}\frac{\delta H_1}{\delta u},
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
H_0=\int dx\;\left(\frac{1}{6}u^3-\frac{1}{2}u'^2\right),\;\, \mathcal{D}=\partial_x^3+\frac{1}{3}\left(\partial_x u+u\partial_x\right),\;\, H_1=\int dx\;\left(\frac{1}{2}u^2\right).
\end{align}

I'm asking if somebody knows an article, reference or its own knowledge, where the bi-Hamiltonian structure of the sine-Gordon equation could be read explicitely.

Comment: Is $\delta$ supposed to be $\partial$?

Comment: @K.defaoite, I had a typo, my mistake. $\frac{\delta H}{\delta u}$ is the functional derivative of $H$ with respect to $u$.